# Regex to extract an "id" separated by string (or begin)

Tags: regex

I need to extract `IDs` from a string : `1;#ChapitreA;#2;#ChapitreB;`
Here, IDs are `1` and `2`

I tried `(^|;#)([0-9]?)(;)` but it returns too many results => [Here](https://regex101.com/r/8renbK/1)

Or behind :

```
0-2     1;
0-0     null
0-1     1
1-2     ;
12-16   ;#2;
12-14   ;#
14-15   2
15-16   ;
```

Constraint : I cannot use `groups` as this RegEx will be use in `Nintex Workflow` which doesn't support it. By the way I can't use any programming language neither to manage the result.. I need the RegEx to return the exact result I need (IDs) and nothing more.

Solution : `(?:(?<=^)|(?<=;#))\d+(?=;)`

Comment: It is not a problem, get Group 2 value. If you remove unnecessary capturing groups, `(?:^|;#)(\d+);` will only contain Group 1 where your value is.

Comment: wiktor-stribiżew unfortunatly I need to find a regex that returns **only** the wanted result as I use it inside "software" that does allow me to manage results ..

Comment: Then use lookarounds, `(?<=^|;#)\d+(?=;)` or `(?:(?<=^)|(?<=;#))\d+(?=;)`

Comment: post what the desired out should be

Comment: @golden-lion "I need to extract IDs [...] IDs are 1 and 2" ;)

Comment: txt="""1;#ChapitreA;#2;#ChapitreB;"""
print(re.findall(r'\d+', txt))  Is this what you want?  Are you looking for the pattern #2;#   - a # followed by a number follewed by a ;#

Comment: print(re.findall(r'(?<=;\#)*\d+(?=\;)', txt))   I used #; proceeding optional then the number followed by a ; as the search pattern.   The code means capture a group and look behind for ;# pattern then find one or more digits then look ahead for a ;

Comment: Actually the pattern is `;#ID;#` or `ID;#` at the start of the string. I cannot use groups as `Nintex Workflow` (I am using) isn't compatible with. Preview answer by Wiktor perfectly does what I need. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using groups : `(?:^|;#)(\d+);`
Without using groups : `(?:(?<=^)|(?<=;#))\d+(?=;)`

Thx @wiktor-stribiżew